# haskell random instance of own datatype

Tags: haskell, random, instance, gloss

I am working on an Asteroid game made in Haskell with Graphics.gloss. Now I have defined a datatype for the asteroids like this:

```
data Asteroid = Asteroid {   asteroidPos:: Point, 
                             asteroidVel   :: Vector,
                             asteroidSize  :: Float }
```

So that it has a Position defined by a point, a velocity defined by a vector and it's size. Now I want to know how I could write an instance of Random for this datatype so that a new asteroid appears at a random time, on a random place with a random velocity. Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Comment: [related](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.10.1/docs/Test-QuickCheck-Arbitrary.html#v:arbitrary).

Comment: Did you try to write the instance? What issue did you find?

Comment: Have you had a look at [random:
 System.Random](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.1/docs/System-Random.html#g:4)? Can you show your efforts in implementing the `Random` interface for your `Asteroid` data-type.

Comment: “At a random time” can't very well be expressed as a `Random` instance. Are you writing your game in a Functional Reactive Programming style, or with a traditional “imperative loop”? In the former case, you could just generate an ordered list of equal-distributed entering-time values. Else you'd rather have to pull a _time interval_ out of an exponential distribution whenever an asteroid appears, and then wait for that time before you generate the next.

Answer (score 1):

There's already a `Random` instance for `Float`. Assuming that you also have `Random` instances for `Vector` and `Point`, you can use them to define a `Random` instance for `Asteroid`:

```
instance Random Asteroid where
  randomR (Asteroid pl vl sl, Asteroid ph vh sh) g =
    let (p, g1) = randomR (pl, ph) g
        (v, g2) = randomR (vl, vh) g1
        (s, g3) = randomR (sl, sh) g2
    in (Asteroid p v s, g3)
  random g =
    let (p, g1) = random g
        (v, g2) = random g1
        (s, g3) = random g2
    in (Asteroid p v s, g3)
```

The `randomR` function takes a range of values, from minimum (low) to maximum (high). How you define a meaningful range of a complex value like `Asteroid`, I'll leave up to you; here, I'm simply assuming that you can pass a low and high `Asteroid` value.

The first step uses the underlying `Random` instance for `Point` by calling `randomR`. `p` is a randomly generated `Point` value, and `g1` is the next random generator value to use.

Likewise, `v` is a randomly generated `Vector` value, generated by the underlying instance for `Vector`.

Finally, `s` is a `Float` generated by `randomR` for `Float`.

The return value is a new `Asteroid` value composed from `p`, `v`, and `s`, plus the most recent generator `g3`.

The implementation of `random` follows the same template.

You could write this code in a prettier form, using e.g. using `MonadRandom`, but for starters, I left the code in its raw form to show how it works.